# Verb that means "to be in a relationship with"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know you can say, *I'm dating him or her*. Is there a verb (an -ing verb in this case) that can be used like that but for *being in a relationship* (the further step)?

Example:

> Sam's not exactly a gay man. He's a transgender. So *technically*
>   Mark'll still be ___ing a woman.

I checked the [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dating?s=t) of dating. Bus as I expected they all mean dating, not being in a relationship.

(Idioms are also welcomed.)

Comment: There are hundreds if not thousands of euphemisms for "being in a relationship".

Comment: @Hot Licks I'm looking for a one-word verb like in the example above. I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: One should perhaps take some caution using *transgender* as a noun (cf. *a gay*, *a black*); some references say this usage is sometimes offensive. (On the other hand, it's used as a noun in some recent academic literature, so the proscription isn't uniform.)

Comment: Also, not a verb, but still a single word: "...Mark'll still be *with* a woman." In this usage the sense is probably a little stronger than *dating*.

Comment: Although, @Travis, maybe it's an age thing but when I hear "with a woman", I think of the euphemism for sex.

Comment: Seconding (or, going by the upvotes, fourthing) @Travis’ comment. “He’s a transgender” sounds pejorative—just say, “He’s transgender”. And “Mark’ll” looks awkward; I’d just write it out as “Mark will” if I were you.

Comment: This isn't pertinent to your actual question, but your example phrase is ambiguous to me in a way that could make it potentially offensive. If Sam is a transgender woman, she should not be referred to as a "gay man", and so the sentence is correct, although "technically a woman" is an insensitive way to phrase it. If Sam is a transgender man, then referring to him as a woman is disrespectful to his gender identity. So if this example sentence is one you intend to use in actual conversation or writing, please give it some consideration.

Comment: So technically Mark'll still be `fuck`ing a woman.

Comment: **There is no one universal word** since the whole topic and norms around it are highly culturally-dependent. Even 'dating' is not generally used so much in non-American English ('seeing', 'going out with', 'courting'). If you only want the answer for an American context then you need to specify that.

Comment: "Mark'll still be *involved with* a woman."?

Comment: @Travis Well, the original text is a bit different. The speaker is a lesbian and the *technically* refers to the fact that she will still be in a lesbian relationship. Is that less offensive?

Comment: @janoChen Like most sensitive matters whether someone finds this usage offensive depends on context and, certainly, the sensibilities of the listener themselves. I could speculate about whether a listener would be less likely to take offense if the speaker happens to be a lesbian talking about another woman, but this quickly becomes a matter of politics rather than semantics.

Comment: @janoChen Separately, as recognizer says, the use of *technically* here is potentially dismissive (and hence rude and so potentially offensive) regardless of listener, as a typical person does not regard their own sexuality as a technical matter, i.e., one turning on a technical definition. I would probably avoid this usage, unless you're, say, writing a character you want to portray as dismissive in this way.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I didn't think of that connotation until you mentioned it, though at least to my ear there isn't much danger of confusion here. I would probably never use that sense in the present tense: If I were feeling poetic I might say, "He's never been with a woman." But I'd never say "He's with a woman" to mean he was having sex with a woman, either presently or on a continuing basis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***"Seeing"*** is used as a euphemism for dating:

> "Sam's not exactly a gay man. He's a transgender. So technically Mark'll still be ***seeing*** women."

And ***"seeing"*** can also be used for a relationship as in:

> "You know that cute guy in the marketing department?  We're *seeing* each other."

Comment: _Seeing_ was my immediate thought, too; but in the context given, it reads like ‘dating’ to me. I would understand it as Mark and Sam being at a pre-relationship stage if I read it with _seeing_. In fact, I think I’d be more likely to read _dating_ here as being further towards the steady-relationship end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

***Courting*** comes to mind, if you're looking for something that implies an intent to solidify a relationship at some point in the future as something exclusive.

Comment: That would quite unequivocally mean that Mark is _trying to enter into_ a relationship with Sam, but they aren’t in a relationship already.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet : not necessarily, it's culturally-dependent. Some (non-American) cultures have a long period where the guy is expected to exclusively court one girl before she officially becomes his girlfriend.

Comment: @smci Well, yes, exactly. Once they are in the relationship, they’re out of the courting phase.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: No, the American equivalent would not draw that distinction. To try to find a rough American equivalent, you could compare to the period in dating where one(/both) of the parties has not decided to be exclusive.

Comment: @smci I’m not sure exactly what distinction you’re saying the American equivalent (to what?) would not draw? To the _very_ limited extent that I’ve ever heard speakers of AmE born this side of 1900 talking about ‘courting’ people at all, they were always talking about pursuing someone in the hopes or with the expectation of entering into a relationship with that person, actual relationship (or marriage) status being the _goal_ of the courting ritual. I have never heard anyone, AmE or BrE, use ‘courting’ as a synonym for being in a steady, long-term relationship with someone.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: South Asia (e.g. India) and Southeast Asia (e.g. [Courtship in the Philippines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtship_in_the_Philippines)) also speak English but apply very different cultural norms to the phases of relationships; there are no direct equivalents. In Filipino culture, traditional courtship lasts several years.

Comment: After thinking about it & reading the comments discussion, I think it's probably not the best term. It implies more a state of someone seeking to establish a more permanent or stronger relationship with a person than one currently has, regardless of the current state of the relationship.  So, it poorly fits OP's description.

Answer (score 0):

***partnering*** is used in this sense, although it has a lot of non-sexual interpretations which might be confusing if the listener wasn't already familiar with the nature of Sam and Mark's relationship.

Comment: The context might disambiguate, but my first thought when reading the example sentence with _partnering_ was that Mark was Sam’s dance partner or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

How about "we are close romantically" or "we are intimate".
or "we are in a relationship"?

Comment: OP is looking for a single word: a verb (well, a gerund).

Answer (score -1):

**Sleeping with** is idiomatic in North America.

Comment: It's not at all synonymous with 'being in a relationship'. You can be in a relationship without sex, and you can sleep with someone without being in a relationship.

Comment: It's hard to have sex without being in some sort of (perhaps very short term) relationship, unless you're including solo sex. And one doesn't sleep with oneself, so it seems clear enough to me. Anyway, I was definitely going for 'sex' and not 'partnership.'

Comment: no it isn't, it's quite common (in North America). It even has a name: FWB or NSA. There are entire dating sites for hookups: *Tinder*